# What is multilingual vs monolingual corpus?

Tags: nlp

If I have a corpus which has Hindi script and Hindi transliteration with English script. Is it multilingual or monolingual corpus?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fool-proof way of converting the Hindi transliteration to Hindi script (or vice versa), then you should do it, and you will have a monolingual corpus. If not, it is multilingual, from an algorithmic standpoint.

Caveat: Even if we can convert all text into the same script reliably, we sometimes need to be careful about treating everything in the same language. For example, the Hindi spelling, grammar, and usage may differ between the text in Hindi script and the transliterated text (usually user-generated content like comments on websites). Depending on the use case, we may want to treat transliterated text as a separate language.